# Deployment error -

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm am getting an error when deploying ADF pipelines. I don't understand how to resolve this error message:

```
Pipeline Populate SDW_dbo_UserProfiles from SDW_dbo_CTAS_ApptraxDevices is in Failed state. Cannot set active period Start=05/30/2017 00:00:00, End=05/29/2018 23:59:59 for pipeline 'Populate SDW_dbo_UserProfiles from SDW_dbo_CTAS_ApptraxDevices' due to conflicts on Output: SDW_dbo_UserProfiles with Pipeline: Populate SDW_dbo_UserProfiles from SDW_dbo_Manifest, Activity StoredProcedureActivityTemplate, Period: Start=05/30/2017 00:00:00, End=05/30/2018 00:00:00
.
Try changing the active period or using autoResolve option when setting the active period.
```

I'm am authoring and deploying from within Visual Studio 2015. All of my pipelines have the same values for Start and End.

"start": "2017-05-30T00:00:00Z",
"end": "2018-05-29T23:59:59Z"

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Were you successful in adding the start and end times back?

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio can be fun sometimes when it comes to validating your JSON because not only does it check everything in your solution it also validates against what you already have deployed in Azure!

I suspect this error will be because there is a pipeline that you have already deployed that now differs from Visual Studio. If you delete the affected pipeline from ADF in Azure manually and then redeploy you should be fine.

Sadly the tooling isn't yet clever enough to understand which values should take presedence and be overwritten at deployment time. So for now it simiply errors because of a mismatch, any mismatch!

You will also encounter similar issues if you remove datasets from your solution. They will still be used for validation at deployment time because the wizard first deploys all new things before trying to delete the old. I've fed this back to Microsoft already as an issue that needs attention for complex solutions with changing schedules.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I've deleted all objects from the Data Factory and removed all Start and End datetime from the pipelines.  It now deploys cleanly.  This will work during development but I have a concern about re-adding the Start and End datetimes prior to going to testing.  Let's see what happens.

Comment: Yup, I share your frustrations! Normally its just going back in time thats the problem if you want to remove already provisioned activites. My advice would be to make sure you have the time slice start dates defined clearly for each dataset before going into production. If my suggestion solved your issue I would appreicate your upvotes and it being marked as the answer. Thanks

Comment: I gave the upvote and will mark as answer once I put the Start and End dates back in and get this thing running.